# DeltaDNA: SQL Query to check for how many users an event was fired once, twice etc

Tags: sql

I'm using Delta DNA which is an analytics platform to understand some player data for a game.

Currently, I need to understand tiers of usage in my activities.
The system works in a way that for each player that completes an activity, an event is fired from the app. one player can play as many times as they like.

I'd like to create a query that tells me how many players played a certain activity(which is represented by a certain event) only 1 time, only 2 times etc.

I can't seem to figure out a way to do that. I do have data mining which allows me a direct SQL query instead of using the Slice&Dice system(drag and drop dimensions).

Can you guys help or direct me in the right way? I know there should be a use of count here but I don't see how to do that correctly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've been trying to understand how to do that and apparently in DeltaDNA there is another table that holds all of the information that you need. It's called user_metrics and is accessed through Analyze -> Data Mining -> select the table from the right upper corner drop down menu.

use "SELECT * FROM user_metrics" to see the structure of the table.